# ReSharper suggests a wrong "Expression is always true"

Tags: c#, .net, resharper-8.0

I found this bug in my current project and then I reproduced in a very simple code, which I share here.

I'm using ReSharper 8.0.2 and Visual Studio 2013.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var orders = new List<Order> { new Order {ClientId = 10}, new Order()};
        var firstOrder = orders.FirstOrDefault();
        if ( firstOrder != null && firstOrder.ClientId.HasValue)
        {
            // In this line resharper suggests that t.ClientId.HasValue is always true. This is wrong.
            var ordersWithClient = orders.Where(t => t.ClientId.HasValue).ToList();   
        }
    }
}

class Order
{
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you found a bug in Resharper you should report it to JetBrains not post a question here.

Comment: in this context ReSharper is saying right see your code orders has one element which is not null

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `orders` has two entries.  The second has a `null` `ClientId`.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: FYI, I'm using R# 8.2.1 and this code does not produce the false suggestion for me.  So, maybe you just need to upgrade.

Comment: Indeed - 8.0.2 is nearly 2 years old...

Comment: I have version 9.2... I do not get the suggestion.

Comment: Hi juharr, I reported this to JetBrains. I just want to share this and look if someone has a suggestion. As you well say, I need to upgrade. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Its because you already have a conditional statement that checks if the `ClientId` has value before before assigning it to a variable. Thus the expression is always true

Comment: The `if` statement is checking the `firstOrder`, but the actual code is dealing with the `orders` which contains an `Order` with a `null` `ClientId`.

Comment: Thats not what his code is validating.  Its validating the first order which the `ClientId` has already been set. Why the expression is always true

Comment: The `if` validates the first order, but Resharper is saying that `t => t.ClientId.HasValue` is always `true`, but that's not correct because `orders` contains one entry where it is in fact `false`.

Comment: ``t => t.ClientId.HasValue`` validates the first entry as does the `if` statement correct?

Comment: No the `orders.Where` is going to iterate through all the items in `orders`.

Comment: yes correct, but that also includes that the first/default order as well.